# In Azure Active Directory, is PC status "Workplace Joined" different from "AAD Joined"?

Tags: join, azure-active-directory, mdm, intune

I have PC's that have been logged in using personal Microsoft Account, with a "Work or School Account" added in the "Access Work or School" page of the account settings.

I've adopted Enterprise Mobility + Security E5, and want to manage all devices using Intune.  Under my profile, the devices above are showing status of "Workplace Joined." Somehow, it seems "I'm not there yet." Do I need to start over with these PC's?

Please advise! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> is PC status “Workplace Joined” different from “AAD Joined”?

**Azure AD Join** also makes full use of its Azure AD membership by providing the same great SSO experiences as Azure AD Device Registration and **Workplace Join** / Add a work account when accessing both cloud and on premises applications.

For more details about the differences, refer to this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/trejo/2016/04/09/azure-ad-join-vs-azure-ad-device-registration/).